# Initial Value Of Pointer in C++

Tags: c++, pointers, null, initialization, nullptr

What is the initial value of a point in c++?

```
Texture* texture;
```

what is the value of this pointer, is it nullptr is it NULL?
I heard somwhere that the operating system might choose this is that true and is it safe to declare a pointer like this?

Comment: It depends on context.   If the pointer is a global (e.g. at file scope) or a member of an object that is a global it will be zero-initialised (i.e. a null pointer).  If it is a local variable (or member of an object), of automatic storage duration, it is uninitialised - so its value is indeterminate, and accessing its value (or dereferencing it, since dereferencing a pointer requires accessing its value) gives undefined behaviour.   If the pointer is a member of an object constructed using a constructor, the implementation of that constructor determines how (or if) it is initialised.

Comment: When behaviour is undefined, it is certainly a possibility that the resultant behaviour is somehow sane.   But relying on an uninitialised pointer being initialised to anything in particular (a null pointer, the address of something that happens to be valid) is foolhardy.   The nature of undefined behaviour is that the effects may change (e.g. when the compiler is updated, with phase of the moon, after patching the host operating system, or if the code is built using a different compiler).  The change of effects may or may not be detected (e.g. in your testing).

Answer (score 1):

Depends on where it is allocated. If static then 0. Ie like this

```
#include <stdio.h>
....
Texture* texture; // all statics are initialized to 0
```

On the stack, like this

```
int pooble(){
     Texture* texture;
    ...
}
```

then its value is undefined. Using it results in Undefeined Behaviour

function local statics are also initialized to 0

```
int pooble(){
     static Texture* texture; // =0
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> What is the initial value of a point in c++?

Just like a built-in type, if you don't **initialize** a pointer at **local/block scope** then it will have an **indeterminate value**. Using this uninitialized pointer variable will lead to **undefined behavior**.

> **Undefined behavior** means anything<sup>1</sup> can happen *including but not limited to* the program giving your expected output. But **never rely**(or make conclusions based) on the output of a program that has undefined behavior.

This is why it is advised that:

> always initialize built-in types and pointers in local/block scope.

That is, you should initialize the pointer `texture` as shown below:

```
Texture *texture = nullptr; //the pointer currently doesn't point to any Texture object
```

Note i have used `nullptr` and `NULL` in the above statement to initialize the `texture` object.

[Bjarne Stroustrup says](https://www.stroustrup.com/bs_faq2.html#null),

> **Should I use NULL or 0?**
>
> In C++, the definition of NULL is 0,
> so there is only an aesthetic
> difference. **I prefer to avoid macros,
> so I use 0.** Another problem with NULL
> is that people sometimes mistakenly
> believe that it is different from 0
> and/or not an integer. In pre-standard
> code, NULL was/is sometimes defined to
> something unsuitable and **therefore
> had/has to be avoided**. That's less
> common these days.
>
> If you have to name
> the null pointer, call it **`nullptr`**;
> that's what it's going to be called in
> **C++0x**. Then, **`nullptr`** will be a
> keyword.

---

<sup><sup>1</sup>For a more technically accurate definition of undefined behavior see [this](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub) where it is mentioned that: **there are no restrictions on the behavior of the program**.</sup>

Answer (score 0):

The C++ language does not specify any initial value for a pointer, leaving it uninitialized could lead to undefined behavior.  Some compilers will have a debug mode where a pointer will be initialized to a value that is likely to lead to a crash.

Comment: Except for statics, they are all initialized to 0

Comment: @pm100 I forgot about statics, but even if the standard guarantees their contents I would explicitly initialize it myself.